# Create Event Tracking With Google Analytics Universal

Tags: google-analytics

I want to know how many visitors click on my call me button. I have added the following script in my html head:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1', 'mydomain.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

And, this is my "call me" image button:

```
<a href="tel:1234567890" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'cat', 'action', 'label', { 'hitCallback': function() { document.location = 'tel:1234567890'; }}); return false;">
<img src="images/call.gif" alt="call me" width="306px" height="150px" border="0" />
</a>
```

And in my analytics panel I go to Admin>>Goals>>New Goal>> give it a name and chose Event option and then I put my cat, action, label, value(equals to 1) and SAVE.

It is still not working. I see 0 events and I know that I had some.. Is something wrong with my code?

Comment: Shouldn't events automatically show up in your events when triggered? As in; you don't need to set up events in your goals.

Comment: But is did it and still, as you see, its not working.. what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Does the event register at all? Or can't you import your event as a goal?

Comment: Found this: http://www.swellpath.com/2013/12/universal-analytics-using-hitcallback/ with the following code example: onclick="var href = this.href; ga('send','event','outbound','click', this.href, {'hitCallback': function(){document.location = href;}}); return false;"